# modify my code and save it as a text file inside a function using python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, call

How to read a list and save it in a text file inside a one function using python3? please someone help me

```python
string=["my name is john"," my anniversary is on 04/01/1997","yes","ok"] 

def create_file(file_name): 
   for i in string:
       with open(file_name, "w") as input_file:
           print(" {}".format(i), file = input_file)

def read_file(file_name):
   create_file(file_name)
   input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
read_file('file.txt')

with open('file.txt','r') as f: 
   input_file = f.readlines()
```

Expected Output: (in text file)

```
my name is john
my anniversary is on 04/01/1997
yes
ok
```

Comment: You have a lot of illogical, almost random bits and pieces in your code. Try to write your code in English first: what should be done and _in what order_?

Comment: made changes please see my above code and want to save a list in text file inside a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output, this is the code.

```
string=["my name is john"," my anniversary is on 04/01/1997","yes","ok"]

def create_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "w") as input_file:
        for sentence in string:
            # Append new line and write
            input_file.write(sentence + '\n')

file_name = "your_filename.txt"

create_file(file_name)
```

Comment: thank u so much but text file saved as in what name?

Comment: Suggest looking up your basics in python. Whatever string you assign to filename. 
filename = "file.txt"

Comment: if i m giving like that i got error as filename not defined error